# Stripe hangs after OAuth connection using passport-stripe

Tags: oauth, passport.js, stripe-connect

I am developing a prototype of using [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts), using [`passport-stripe`](https://github.com/mathisonian/passport-stripe) to authenticate the user so they will be paid. I have set up the middleware, and I can get to the Stripe Connect OAuth page. I press skip (as my Stripe account is in development mode, this is enabled) so I do not have to fill in the details. However, Stripe now hangs on redirecting me back to my application. Stripe has connected the account as it appears in the Connected Accounts screen (I revoke the access each time I try again).

Here is my code:

```
import passport from 'passport'
import passportStripe from 'passport-stripe'

const StripeStrategy = passportStripe.Strategy
const STRIPE_CLIENT_ID = '...'
const STRIPE_API_KEY = '...'

module.exports = passport.use(new StripeStrategy({
  clientID: STRIPE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: STRIPE_API_KEY,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/pay"
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, stripe_properties, done) => {
    (() => {}, (err, user) => { // wasn't sure about this line, the passport-stripe docs are unclear
      done(err, user)
    })
}))
```

and in my server router:

```
app.get('/auth/stripe', passport.authenticate('stripe', { scope: 'read_write' }))
app.get('/pay', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('stripe', (err, user, info) => {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  if (!user) { return res.redirect('/'); }
  res.render('pay')
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

`/pay` is my redirect URI, which is also specified in the Stripe Connect application settings, and I have a 'pay' EJS view specified. I have also used the [passport.js authentication docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate).